# Cannot log into chat from Go SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, login

I've been trying to log into chat, but I've been ending up on the "oops page" with the cat. Here's what I did:

From Go SE (`go.stackexchange.com`), where I was logged in, I clicked on the "chat" link and from there the "go" chat box.

This sent me to the chat page with a link to log in first (`https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackexchange.com%2frooms%2f1747%2fgame-of-go`).

On that page, I clicked on the "login" link at the top, which failed and reloaded the page. My browser, Chrome, passed all the GlobalAuth tests. Clicking on the "log in via Stack Exchange" link sent me to [the oops page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/login/global-fallback).

Comment: Could you try again? It should work now.

Comment: @balpha: yes it's working now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that; there was a (pretty unnecessary) check that blew up with the recent changes to how user account are managed network-wide. Fixed now.